# Probability n Dice Results are subset of m Dice Results

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Let D(n,m) be the probability that a multiset of n dice results will be a submultiset of m dice results.

Multiset indicates repeats are counted: If n=3, {3,3,4} is a submultiset of {3,3,4,5,6} but not of {3,4,5,6}.

The following exact formulas for n=1,2,3 agree with simulation but I would like some way to calculate D(n,m) for n>3 more accurately than simulation.

Ideas? Possibly using generating functions- I'm not sure?

D(1,m)=
1-(5/6)^m

D(2,m)=
(1/6)*(1-(5/6)^m-m*(5/6)^(m-1)*(1/6))
+(5/6)*(1-2*(5/6)^m+(4/6)^m)

D(3,m)= 
(1/6)^2*(1-(5/6)^m-m*(5/6)^(m-1)*(1/6)-COMBIN(m,2)*(5/6)^(m-2)*(1/6)^2)
+(15/36)*(1-2*(5/6)^m-m*(5/6)^(m-1)*(1/6)+(5/6)^m*((4/5)^m+m*(4/5)^(m-1)*(1/5)))
+(5/6)*(4/6)*(1-3*(5/6)^m+3*(4/6)^m-(3/6)^m)

Comment: What about repeats?  Are you including events such as {3,3,4} (which should be a subset of {3,3,4,5,6} but *not* of {3,4,5,6})?

Comment: @Tad: Looking at the expression for $D(2,m)$, it seems the $(1/6)$ deals with the case where the $2$ dice are the same and the $(5/6)$ case where they are different

Comment: Thanks Tad and Henry, I edited to say repeats are counted!

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

Perhaps you could extend your question to $D(n,m,s)$ being the probability that the multiset of results from rolling $n$ $s$-sided dice is a submultiset of the results from rolling $m$ other $s$-sided dice.

If $\displaystyle Q(a,d,s)={d \choose a}\frac{(s-1)^{d-a}}{s^d}$ is the probability that $d$ $s$-sided dice show a pre-specified value $a$ times, then I think you have $$\displaystyle D(n,m,s) = \sum_{a=0}^n \sum_{b=a}^m Q(a,n,s)  \,Q(b,m,s) \,D(n-a,m-b,s-1)$$ with $D(n,m,s)=0$ when $n \gt m$ and $D(n,m,1)=1$ when $0 \le n \le m$.

This recursion seems to give the following probabilities for $6$-sided dice:

```
  0         1          2          3          4           5           6
0 1 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.000000000 1.000000000
1 0 0.1666667 0.30555556 0.42129630 0.51774691 0.598122428 0.665102023
2 0 0.0000000 0.05092593 0.12808642 0.21617798 0.305984225 0.392200360
3 0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.02134774 0.06539352 0.126639660 0.198346527
4 0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.01089892 0.038119427 0.081405115
5 0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.006353238 0.024388941
6 0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.004064824
```

and the row starting "`2 0 0.0000000 0.05092593 0.12808642`" has the same values as given by your $D(2,m)$ formula, which is encouraging.

For what it is worth, here is some R code for the recurrence:

```
Q <- function(a,d,s){ choose(d,a)*(s-1)^(d-a)/s^d }  

maxn     <- 10
maxm     <- 19 # should be at least maxn
maxsides <-  6
D <- matrix(rep(0,(maxm+1)*(maxn+1)), ncol=maxm+1)
rownames(D) <- 0:maxn
colnames(D) <- 0:maxm
for (n in 0:maxn){ for (m in n:maxm){ D[n+1,m+1] <- 1 }}
print(paste("Dice with", 1,"side, probabilities:"))
print(D)
for (sides in 2:maxsides){
    oldD <- D
    D <- matrix(rep(0,(maxm+1)*(maxn+1)), ncol=maxm+1)
    rownames(D) <- 0:maxn
    colnames(D) <- 0:maxm
    for (n in 0:maxn){ for (m in n:maxm){
        summing <- 0 
        for (a in 0:n){ summing <- summing + 
            Q(a,n,sides) * sum(Q(a:m,m,sides)* oldD[n−a+1,m−(a:m)+1])}
        D[n+1,m+1] <- summing }}
    print(paste("Dice with", sides,"sides, probabilities:"))
    print(D)
    }
```

Comment: Oooh this agrees for D(3,m) too! Thank you Henry :)

Comment: Do we believe that this is a correct formula for any n,m,s? It looks this way, but usage of *seems* gives an air of uncertainty. I'm also for an answer to this exact problem (with variable dice side too), so I'm wondering if it's safe to use.

Comment: @zespri: This is StackExchange so anything here is *"use at your own risk"* and *"check simple cases first to make sure it is calculating what you expect"*

Comment: Sorry, I really used very bad wording. What you said in that comment was more or less obvious to me. What I wanted to do is to explore a little bit your level of certainty here and reasons for it. Thanks.

Comment: @zespri: It makes sense to me, while matching $D(2,m)$ and apparently according to Ray Kinane $D(3,m)$.  But beyond that I cannot promise anything.